# KeyError: 'PATH' when running docker-compose up from Fabric

Tags: python, docker-compose, fabric

I was trying to run docker-compose using Fabric, but when I run the docker-compose up command using Fabric I got the following error:

```
[52577] Failed to execute script docker-compose
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 71, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 127, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1080, in up
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1076, in up
  File "compose/project.py", line 475, in up
  File "compose/service.py", line 352, in ensure_image_exists
  File "compose/service.py", line 1217, in pull
  File "compose/progress_stream.py", line 101, in get_digest_from_pull
  File "compose/service.py", line 1182, in _do_pull
  File "site-packages/docker/api/image.py", line 381, in pull
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 48, in get_config_header
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 96, in resolve_authconfig
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 127, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore
  File "site-packages/dockerpycreds/store.py", line 20, in __init__
  File "site-packages/dockerpycreds/utils.py", line 12, in find_executable
  File "distutils/spawn.py", line 176, in find_executable
  File "os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
KeyError: 'PATH'
Failed to up the env
```

When I run docker-compose up from the terminal it works fine.

```
@task
def up(c):
    if c.run('docker-compose up', warn=True).failed:
        print ("Failed to up the env")
```

Comment: I think this must be missing some environment variable, or tty session. I'm getting the same when trying to run docker-compose via PHP's Synfony Process component, but it appears to work when using `passthru()` (which I think inherits everything from the current shell.

Answer (score 2):

As my comment suggested, it seems `docker-composer up` when it needs to do a `build` at least, needs the `PATH` environment variable to be set. To fix, I just forwarded the `PATH` from the current session to the child process (in PHP sorry!):

```php
$compose = new Process( 'docker-compose up -d', '', [
    'VOLUME' => getcwd(),
    'PATH' => getenv( 'PATH' ),
] );
```